# RFID based reading and writing in C

Tags: c#, rfid

I have to make a RFID based attendance system where i have to write into the database once reading from the tag and finding out which student it is.
I will using C# to build that RFID can anyone help me to find a tutorial how to make RFID with C ?

Comment: Finding tutorials is off-topic in SO.

Answer (score 1):

Every RFID device has a SDK which gives you api to read from the controller.

Also if you want to be device independent you can design an adapter with a facade.

When you read the data you can write it to db like normal data